# Why doesn't my small custom function work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a custom function that is not working as expected. This part of the code  `$(carta).stop().css("visibility","visible").fadeIn();`

and this

```
$(carta).stop().fadeOut(250);
```

are not beeing triggered, but if I change the carta var for the id ("#carta1") it works. Does anybody knows what I should change for the function to work correctly?

Here's the code;

```
function yes(meal,carta){
    var fadeTo_null = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#probando").stop().fadeTo(250,0);
        $("#probando").css("visibility","hidden");
        $(carta).stop().css("visibility","visible").fadeIn(); 

    };

    var fadeTo_back = function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#probando").stop().fadeTo(500,1);
        $("#probando").css("visibility","visible");
        $(carta).stop().fadeOut(250);

    };

    $(meal, carta).hover(fadeTo_null,fadeTo_back);

};


    $(document).ready(function(){

    yes("#frueh" ,"#carta1");
});
```

Comment: do `yes("#fueh", "#carta1");` Your need to adjust your parameters.

Comment: looks like you want "#frueh" ,"#carta1" instead of "#frueh ,#carta1" as the param you pass into yes()

Comment: You need some more quotation marks. "#frueh" ,"#carta1"

Comment: i added the quotation marks as you all recommeded ("#frueh" ,"#carta1") but now nothing works :/

Comment: Thank you all for the help.. i don´t know why.. but i  call the function as 1 parameter   yes("#frueh,#carta1"); and in the function seld i splitet them with   var splited = meal.split(',') and then called         $(spliti[1]).stop().css("visibility","visible").fadeIn();  and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You pass variable objects to your function like this:

```
yes(meal, $('#carta'));
```

Then use the variable inside the function like this:

```
carta.stop().css("visibility","visible").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one string but 2 arguments

Change to:

```
yes("#frueh","#carta1");//now have 2 params
```

Then when you need both you can use:

```
$([meal, carta].join())// $('#frueh,#carta1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close the quotes of the parameters and close the parentheses of the ready function.

Code that is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    yes("#frueh ,#carta1");
};
```

Code that is working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    yes("#frueh","#carta1");
});
```